# Nuxt returns '__ob__: Observer' when return array in async

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm trying to implement this kind of code, but when I do this array gets '__ob__: Observer' ( which I don't understand what it is).
I expected this results in that array gets array data type but seems not.
What do I go wrong?

```
<li v-for="item in array"><li>
```

---

```
async asyncData ({ }) {
 // mock
 return {
  array: [
   { number: 1},
   { number: 2},
   { number: 3},
   { number: 4}
  ]
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`__ob__: Observer` is vue telling you that it is observing the array. It should be expandable to tell you more but it shouldn't be related to your problem. I think the reason you have no output is that you aren't actually asking for it as you have it now. Perhaps try:

```
<ul v-for="(item, index) in array" :key="index"> //you should bind to a key.
  <li>{{item.number}}</li>
</ul>
```